# Find file using for loop in certain folders

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to find out ugraf.exe files from mapped drive. Below command loops through all folders on current drive to find file - `ugraf.exe` .

```
For /R %A In (ugraf.exe)Do @Echo %~dpnxA
```

I want to find the `ugraf.exe` in folders starting from `ugnx*` and existing only in `ugii` folder.

```
O:\ugnxxxxx\...\wntx64\kits\ugii\ugraf.exe
```

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: `for /D %A in ("O:\ungx*") do pushd "%~A" && ((for /D /R %B in ("ugii") do if exist "%~B\ugraf.exe" echo/%~B\ugraf.exe) & popd)`

Comment: @aschipfl, getting lines as ouput, seems like looping through all folders of 1st `ugnx*` :
`if exist "O:\ugnx100\nx10.24\....\fsnac3\"ugii"\ugraf.exe" echo/O:\ugnx100\nx10.24\...\fsnac3\"ugii"\ugraf.exe`

Comment: Is the issue that in `for /D /R %B in ("ugii")`, the string within the parentheses is supposed to be a glob? If you change any one of the characters to a `?`, it should fix that, _(e.g. `u?ii`)_, however, you'd have to be sure that the character you change doesn't then match another none required directory too.

Comment: You are also receiving the command echos; start the Command Prompt as `cmd /Q`, then try again, or place `@` symbols before commands/blocks…

Answer (score 2):

Unless there are a lot of large directories in the root of `O:` whose names do not begin with the string `ugnx`, it seems as if it would be simpler to just search for the file, then check its output for `ugnx` and `ugii` directories in the returned path string:

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%where.exe" /R "O:\." "ugraf.exe" 2>NUL | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /I /R "^O:\\ugnx*\\ugii\\ugraf\.exe$"
```

You could even do that with the `Dir` command, instead of using `where.exe`:

```batch-file
@Dir /B /S /A:-D "O:\ugraf.exe" 2>NUL | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /I /R "^O:\\ugnx*\\ugii\\ugraf\.exe$"
```

If you wanted to capure it from a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop):

```batch-file
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%where.exe" /R "O:\." "ugraf.exe" 2>NUL | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /I /R "^O:\\ugnx*\\ugii\\ugraf\.exe$""') Do @Echo %%G
```

Or using the `Dir` command instead of `where.exe`

```batch-file
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('"Dir /B /S /A:-D "%%G\ugraf.exe" 2>NUL | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /I /R "^O:\\ugnx*\\ugii\\ugraf\.exe$""') Do @Echo %%G
```

---

If the directories in the root of `O:` on your `ugnx*` directory level could be large or many, then just pass that from an initial `For /D` loop:

```batch-file
@For /D %%G In ("O:\ungx*") Do @For /F "Delims=" %%H In ('""%__AppDir__%where.exe" /R "%%G" "ugraf.exe" 2>NUL | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /I /R "^O:\\ugnx*\\ugii\\ugraf\.exe$""') Do @Echo %%H
```

Or using the `Dir` command instead of `where.exe`

```batch-file
@For /D %%G In ("O:\ungx*") Do @For /F "Delims=" %%H In ('"Dir /B /S /A:-D "%%G\ugraf.exe" 2>NUL | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /I /R "^O:\\ugnx*\\ugii\\ugraf\.exe$""') Do @Echo %%G
```

Or a `For /F` loop:

```batch-file
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /S /A:D "O:\ungx*" 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Delims=" %%H In ('""%__AppDir__%where.exe" /R "%%G" "ugraf.exe" 2>NUL | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /I /R "^O:\\ugnx*\\ugii\\ugraf\.exe$""') Do @Echo %%H
```

And once again, using `Dir`, instead of `where.exe`:

```batch-file
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /S /A:D "O:\ungx*" 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Delims=" %%H In ('"Dir /B /S /A:-D "%%G\ugraf.exe" 2>NUL | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /I /R "^O:\\ugnx*\\ugii\\ugraf\.exe$""') Do @Echo %%H
```

Comment: Yes, there are tons of files and folders on O drive. I'm running all 3 solutions.

Comment: The number of files and folders on the `O:` drive is not what I said, @Experimenter. I was deliberately specific, the issue, _(speed)_, would only be if there were a lot of large trees in the root of `O:` adjacent to `O:\ugnx*`. The time would be wasted going through those trees first. I have therefore added an additional `For /D` and `For /F` option for those scenarios. Feel free to test them all for speed. You could also try replacing `"%__AppDir__%where.exe" /R "%%G" "ugraf.exe"` with `Dir /B /S /A:-D "%%G\ugraf.exe"` in those examples to see if it's quicker for you too, *(answer updated)*.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe your results with `findstr` commands:

```
... | findstr /I "O:\ugn" | findstr /I "ugii\ugraf.exe"
```

The `/I` stands for case insensitivity.
The `findstr /I "O:\ugn"` checks that the main directory is indeed "ugnxxxxx".
The `findstr /I "ugii\ugraf.exe"` makes sure you only get the ones in the "ugii" directory.

Comment: The **`\ `** and **`.`** characters are special in **`findstr`**.